# Bixby Studio: "Unknown key: 'headers'"

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm trying to set up endpoints.bxb with a remote endpoint but it is giving me an error... I haven't been able to figure out why it is showing up. I'm doing exactly the same as the Github example [http-master](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/http).

**ERROR Unknown key: 'headers'**

```
endpoints {
  authorization {
    none
  }
  action-endpoints {
    action-endpoint(Find) {
        accepted-inputs ()
        remote-endpoint ("{remote.url}/find") {
          method (POST)
        }
        headers {
          header (Content-Type: application/json)
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is due to the `headers` tag not being nested inside of the `remote-endpoint` tag.

Comment: Oh I see. Then the guide on the dev bixby site has it wrong under Remote Endpoints section: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.configuring-endpoints

Comment: Yes, that looks like a code snippet that is still referencing the old structure. We will work internally with our teams to update it. Thank you, for bringing it to our attention.